# Encrypt casper-rw file for use with Easy2Boot

Tags: encryption, luks, bootable, disk-encryption

I have created an Easy2Boot multiboot USB drive. Currently it contains two ISOs - Kali Linux 2016 and Linux Mint. I have created persistent ext2 filestore for both ISOs and configured them using the tutorial from the Easy2Boot website [here](http://www.easy2boot.com/add-payload-files/persistence/).

In the mnu file for Kali Linux it specifies a way to encrypt the persistent filestore using LUKS. The steps are as follows:

1. `cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb3`
2. `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 my_usb`
3. `mkfs.ext3 -L persistence /dev/mapper/my_usb`
4. `e2label /dev/mapper/my_usb persistence`
5. `mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb`
6. `mount /dev/mapper/my_usb /mnt/my_usb`
7. `echo "/ union" > /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf`
8. `umount /dev/mapper/my_usb`
9. `cryptsetup luksClose /dev/mapper/my_usb`

In the GRUB boot menu for Kali it also has an option to boot from encrypted persistent storage so there must be some configuration required for booting from encryption also.

Does anyone know how I might apply the same concept to my Linux Mint casper-rw file?

Comment: I suspect Kali's live ISO is set up to look for & decrypt an encrypted persistent storage, and Linux Mint's ISO is not. You may have to make your own Linux Mint (based) ISO that will decrypt persistent storage

Comment: I see. I've never made a custom distro before. Have you any advice on where I'd find some good literature or tutorials on where to begin?

Comment: In the past, Linux Mint used to have a guide, practically a step-by-step how-to, and I think even a package called "mintconstructor" too, but they deleted it all a few years ago (not sure why). The URL was http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/918 but now it's dead... a google search still finds some references. One for Ubuntu should work too, I remember "remastersys" maybe? This google search looks fruitful: [how to make your own ubuntu distro](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=how+to+make+your+own+ubuntu+distro)